# Finding geometry of an area with overpass API

Tags: overpass-api

I am trying to find the geometry of a building from a particular latitude longitude. So my idea was to use a coord-query to get all areas in which the lat,lng. Using http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter, I get all the areas and I can filter to get only the nodes that are buildings.

Now I have an area, for example:

```
{ id: '2542062474',
    'addr:city': 'Nice',
    amenity: 'place_of_worship',
    building: 'yes',
    denomination: 'protestant',
    name: 'Église Protestante Unie de Nice Saint-Esprit',
    religion: 'christian',
    source: 'cadastre-dgi-fr source : Direction Générale des Impôts - Cadastre. Mise à jour : 2011' }
```

I thought it would be easy to get the geometry of this area but I can't find any way of doing that ? I must be missing something.

In http://overpass-turbo.eu, I enter the script:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “area”
  area(2542062474);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

but the result does not include the geometry. How do I get the geometry of an area ?

Thanks !

Here is my script, for the moment: https://gist.github.com/ptbrowne/60d7338502de1d16ac46

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Areas](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Areas) are an internal data type of Overpass. You can use [pivot](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Area_pivot_.28pivot.29) to get the geometry:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
area(2542062474);
way(pivot);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, what I did was to read a bit more the doc and to find out that to get the **way** associated with an **area**, I needed to substract `2400000000` from the area `id`.

Then I could only query for the way. From area id `2542062474`, I substract `2400000000`, I get `142062474`.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
way(142062474);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

It works, but I think the `pivot` answer by @Alex Morega is better since the `2400000000` might change one day. I do not know about performance.